# PostgreSQL 9.3 Amazon RDS gives error while using UUID-OSSP extension for generating uuid

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, rails, postgresql-extensions

I have created DB instance on RDS and used below function. It gave error while with the same PostgreSQL version on a local development machine it works fine.

```
create or replace function uuid() returns uuid as 'uuid-ossp', 'uuid_generate_v1' volatile strict language C;
```

here is the error log:

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for language c
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: permission denied for language c
> SQL state: 42501
> ```

I'm using this function in ruby on rails 3.2 for generating uuid for my schema.

Answer (score 9):

You appear to be attempting to load uuid-ossp extension by loading the .sql file directly. You should not be doing that on any modern PostgreSQL, and it won't work on RDS.

Use

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks Craig! To avoid re-installing the module I add IF NOT EXISTS:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";